# Normalize slashes in URL

Tags: xml, url, xslt, rss, xslt-1.0

Is there an easy way of normalizing the slashes of a URL with XSLT?

In my example I'm converting RSS feeds with XSLT and I want to build the URLs for the tags. I can do this with the following line:

```
<skos:Concept about="{/rss/channel/link}/tag/{@nicename}">
```

or

```
<skos:Concept about="{/rss/channel/link}tag/{@nicename}">
```

Sometimes the `link` has a trailing slash and sometimes not. Is there an easy function, which will make sure that there is always a slash? e.g.:

```
<skos:Concept about="{normalize-slashs(/rss/channel/link/)}tag/{@nicename}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your link contains no spaces, try =

```
translate(normalize-space(translate(/rss/channel/link, '/', ' ')), ' ', '/')
```

---

### Edit:

To remove the closing slash from $string, if it exists:

```
substring($string, 1, string-length($string) - (substring($string, string-length($string))='/'))
```

In XSLT 2.0 this can be shortened by using the ends-with() function.

Comment: @white_gecko Yeah well, that's what "normalizing" does. Try the alternative I have added to my answer.